# Maven errors when building the project for transitive dependencies

Tags: maven-2

The POM for org.apache.cxf:cxf:jar:2.4.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available

Comment: It looks your version is not stored. Try this 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the .pm file that captures the dependency information got corrupted (either when dowloading or is already corrupted in the central repository).  Try a different version